# Could import data and table structure from csv to mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv, sqlalchemy

i have csv file with headers, my task is to create a schema and table using this file and import data to mysql\mssql database, i found good article how to create schema dynamically from csv but i faced with 2 issues:

1. function is recognizing boolean type like varchar(5)

```
cm_mac varchar(0),
partnerid varchar(0),
version varchar(0),
accountid varchar(0),
securityedgeenabled varchar(5)); <-- should be boolean
```

2. When trying to import data, getting

```
"Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Cursor' object has no attribute 'cursor'" "Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
not all arguments converted during bytes formatting")
```

could anyone help me to solve these issues?
[link to this article i mentioned](https://www.sisense.com/blog/python-create-table/)

Code i'm trying to execute

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Enum
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os
import enum
import csv
import ast
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Boolean
import mysql.connector
import MySQLdb

f = open('c:\Projects\python\splunk\secedge072120.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)

longest = []
type_list = []
headers = []


def dataType(val, current_type):
    try:
        # Evaluates numbers to an appropriate type, and strings an error
        ###!!!Here needs to add boolean!!!###
        t = ast.literal_eval(val)
    except ValueError:
        return 'varchar'
    except SyntaxError:
        return 'varchar'
    if type(t) in [int, float]:
        if (type(t) in [int]) and current_type not in ['float', 'varchar']:
            # Use smallest possible int type
            if (-32768 < t < 32767) and current_type not in ['int', 'bigint']:
                return 'smallint'
            elif (-2147483648 < t < 2147483647) and current_type not in ['bigint']:
                return 'int'
            else:
                return 'bigint'
        if type(t) is float and current_type not in ['varchar']:
            return 'decimal'
    elif (type(t) is Boolean or bool):
        return 'boolean'
    else:
        return 'varchar'


for row in reader:
    if len(headers) == 0:
        headers = row
        for col in row:
            longest.append(0)
            type_list.append('')
    else:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            # NA is the csv null value
            if type_list[i] == 'varchar' or row[i] == 'NA':
                pass
            else:
                var_type = dataType(row[i], type_list[i])
                type_list[i] = var_type
        if len(row[i]) > longest[i]:
            longest[i] = len(row[i])
f.close()


insert_headers = (tuple(headers))
insert_values = ()
insert_values = tuple('?' for header in headers)
statement = 'create table if not exists stack_overflow_survey ('

for i in range(len(headers)):
    if type_list[i] == 'varchar':
        statement = (
            statement + '\n{} varchar({}),').format(headers[i].lower(), str(longest[i]))
    else:
        statement = (statement + '\n' + '{} {}' +
                     ',').format(headers[i].lower(), type_list[i])

statement = statement[:-1] + ');'


print(statement)


mydb = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', password='1234',
                       host='127.0.0.1',
                       database='employees')


cur = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = open(r'c:\Projects\python\splunk\secedge072120.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(csv_data)
print(type(reader))
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    ###!!!Here error is happening !!!###
    cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO stack_overflow_survey({headers})' <--Error
                f'VALUES({insert_values})', row)
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()


# cur.execute(statement)
# csv_data = csv.reader('c:\Projects\python\splunk\secedge072120.csv')
```

Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

- For the type detection, the function recognises types by trying to evaluate them as Python constants; for booleans, that means only "True" and "False" will be accepted, but not "true" or "TRUE". You probably want to add an extra clause to the top to recognise booleans regardless of case:

  ```
  if val.lower() in ('true', 'false'):
    return 'boolean'
  ```
- I'm not sure about the error you've pasted, but certainly the INSERT statement has formatting problems where it uses `({headers})` and `({insert_values})`; print it and adjust it so you don't have superfluous brackets and quotes. For example, you might use `({", ".join(headers)})` and `({", ".join(insert_values)})` (more complex if your headers can contain spaces or otherwise need quoting in SQL).

Comment: Thank you, by adding this code i got almost all fields boolean:

Answer (score 0):

sabik,
Thank you, by adding this code i got almost all my fields are boolean:

```
try:
        # Evaluates numbers to an appropriate type, and strings an error
        ###!!!Here needs to add boolean!!!###
        t = ast.literal_eval(val)
    except ValueError:
        if val.lower() in ('true', 'false') or ('True', 'False'):
            return 'boolean'
        else:
            return 'varchar'
    except SyntaxError:
        if val.lower() in ('true', 'false') or ('True', 'False'):
            return 'boolean'
        else:
            return 'varchar'
    if type(t) in ('true', 'false') or ('True', 'False'):
        return 'boolean'
```

By checking my query i got this
query_result = (f'INSERT INTO stack_overflow_survey {insert_headers}'
f'VALUES {insert_values}')

INSERT INTO stack_overflow_survey ('cm_mac', 'PartnerId', 'Version', 'AccountId', 'SecurityEdgeEnabled')VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?')
It seems like my fields names should be without quotes, how could i achieve that with tuples or lists? Thank you

Comment: All the `if` statements ending in `or ('True', 'False')` will always trigger, because it's evaluating whether `('True', 'False')` is non-empty and it is (it has two elements).